# Need help on getting specific information from an excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I work for a company that has multiple locations selling auto parts. I'm wanting to look at the 'freshness' of the inventory, but for a specific year range for specific vehicle(s).

The basic formula I'm using is

```
=COUNTIFS(INVENTORY!$A$2:$A$50000,$B$1,INVENTORY!$I$2:$I$50000,$J$117,INVENTORY!P$2:P$50000,$C$118)
```

Result is 4

The first argument is looking at the location, the second is looking at the particular vehicle.  The third is determining whether the inventory is either 30, 60 or 90 days old, and I'm getting the right information.  What I want to know now is, while looking at those 4 vehicles, how many of those are made between the years 2004 to 2010, so the criteria for the 4th argument has a range within it, not one specific year (I know the result should come back as 1 in either the 30, 60 or 60+ cell).  On the inventory sheet, the years of the vehicles are in column 'E'.  I'm not sure if I need to use imbedded IF statements to specify the year range, or need to rewrite the whole formula.  Can anyone give me some advise on how to write the formula to get this info?

Answer (score 0):

You can add two conditions to your `COUTINFS` on the same `E` column for the year, i.e.

```
=COUNTIFS(INVENTORY!A:A,$B$1,INVENTORY!I:I,$J$117,INVENTORY!P:P,$C$118,
   INVENTORY!E:E, ">=2004", INVENTORY!E:E, "<=2010")
```

The second line above shows the additional consitions. If the range of years is dynamically present in cells, say `C1` and `D1`, the criteria should be composed by concatenation, i.e.

```
=COUNTIFS(INVENTORY!A:A,$B$1,INVENTORY!I:I,$J$117,INVENTORY!P:P,$C$118,
   INVENTORY!E:E, ">="&C1, INVENTORY!E:E, "<="&D1)
'                  ^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^
```